# Change checkbox color and avoid the standard tooltip of ValueState

Tags: tooltip, sapui5

I can change the color of `Chechbox` using `ValueState` property and it works fine, but it also add `tooltip` automatic.

```
valueState: {
    parts: [{
        path: "value"
    }],
    formatter: formatter.StateChanges
},
tooltip: {
    parts: [{
        path: "value"
    }],
    formatter: formatter.StateChangesText // returns "MyMessage"
},
```

Can't able to overwrite the tooltip

[image]

formatter:

```
        StateChangesText: function(var1) {
            if (var1) {
                return 'MyMessag';
            } else {
                return '';
            }

    },
```

Comment: can you also share the code of "StateChangesText" ? This is possible you might be setting some tooltip there

Answer (score 0):

> This is not possible

Checkbox control which you are using does not have any method like [`setValueStateText`](https://sapui5.hana.ondemand.com/#/api/sap.m.Input/methods/setValueStateText)

By default tooltip message will be added based on the state of the checkbox along with the tooltip you are providing.

Comment: yes, sure I looked into the api. its just funny that I can not simply override it

Comment: how about defining a custom control of similar type and do it?

Comment: sure it is one possibility, I will give it a try